# Why are iterators not copyable?

Tags: rust

Many iterators [implement the `Clone` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html), but none of them [implement the `Copy` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html). At least for simple iterators like [`std:slice::Iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html), [the `Clone` implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/slice.rs.html#799-802) looks like a memcpy anyway, so why isn't `Copy` also implemented?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [PR #20790](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/20790):

> This PR also makes iterator non-implicitly copyable, as this was source of subtle bugs in the libraries. You can still use `clone()` to explictly copy the iterator.

Comment: Could you provide an example of one of these subtle bugs?

Comment: @Shepmaster: I can't think of any.  I assume it had something to do with iterators being passed into `for` loops, getting modified, but leaving the *original* iterator unmodified.

Comment: I found [one example](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/27186#issuecomment-123390413), validating your memory.